# Downloading images using requests in Python3

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I need to download an image from a url using Python. I'm using this to do so:

```py
import requests

with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
    with open(img_path, "wb") as f:
        f.write(r.content)
```

In order for me to see the image in the browser, I need to be logged into my account on that site. The image may have been sent by someone else or myself.

The issue is that I am able to download some images successfully, but for other ones, I get an authentication error, i.e. that I'm not logged in.

In that case too, sometimes it downloads a file whose content is this:

```
{"result":"error","msg":"Not logged in: API authentication or user session required"}
```

And sometimes, it downloads the html file of the webpage which asks me to login to view the image.

Why am I getting this error for just some cases and not others? And how should I fix it?

Comment: use HTTPBasicAuth

Answer (score 8):

Use [`Response.content`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.content) to get the image data as bytes and then write it to a file opened in `wb` (**w**rite **b**inary) [mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

```
import requests

image_url = "https://www.python.org/static/community_logos/python-logo-master-v3-TM.png"
img_data = requests.get(image_url).content
with open('image_name.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(img_data)
```

Note, for authorization:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
img_data = requests.get('image_url', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass')).content
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It doesn't work, though. It gives me "invalid API key" (I'm guessing that's because when I tried doing this manually, i.e. opening the link in incognito, then logging in, it redirects me to the home page, not the page where the image is).
Besides, I can't be using this since a bunch of users will be using this script.
I also still don't understand why it works in some cases and doesn't work in others?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the response.raw file object, or iterate over the response.

```
import requests
import shutil
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

r = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'), stream=True)
if r.status_code == 200:
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        r.raw.decode_content = True
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

Comment: what would you put for path? if you want it to go to your downloads folder, do you need to put its path there?

Comment: @LarissaFord Yes, the path is the location where you want to save that file.